# How do I create this descending line of numbers in Java?

Tags: java, for-loop, methods, while-loop

Im trying to create a descending triangle of numbers like this in Java:

> 4
>
> 3 3
>
> 2 2 2
>
> 1 1 1 1

The user inputs the first number and then it's supposed to create the descending triangle and honestly I don't know how to figure it out.

I haven't really tried that much I'm just lost :)

Here's my code so far:

```
public static void numberlines(){
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Welcome to number lines, enter a number and I'll give you some other numbers in a line...");

    int usernum;
    int counter = 0;
    int count = 0;
    char tab = 9;
    int i;

    usernum = getInt();

    while (counter != usernum){
        if (usernum > counter) { 
            usernum--;
            System.out.println(+ usernum);
        }else if (usernum < counter){
            usernum++;
            System.out.println(+usernum);
        }   
    }//while
}//numberlines
```

Right now it just prints the descending line of numbers but I'm pretty sure there's a lot more to it. If anyone has any suggestions or ideas that would be awesome. Thanks

Comment: Learn about using nested loops. Unfortunately, your current attempt is far off from reaching the target.

Comment: You could also plot the numbers on a graph vs. the number of times each gets printed, there's a simple relationship there.

Comment: yeah I figured it was pretty far off,  the assignment did mention using nested loops

Comment: @purplepandapoof : Well, I suggest you learning about them and trying it first on your own and then if you are stuck come back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by nested while loops:

```
  public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Welcome to number lines, enter a number and I'll give you some other numbers in a line...");

        int usernum;
        int i = 1;
        usernum = in.nextInt();

        while(i <= usernum){
            int j = 1;
            while(j<=i){
                System.out.print(usernum-i+1);
                j++;
            }
            System.out.println();
            i++;
        }//while
    }//numberlines
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int usernum = s.nextInt();
    for(int i = 1; i <= usernum; i++){
      for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++){
        System.out.print(usernum-i+1);
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
}
```